# rails.vim and custom controllers location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rails.vim

I love Rails.vim but I have a problem with using it in some projects. I have two places for controllers in one of my apps:

```
app/controllers
app/controllers/v1/api
```

Can I configure (perhaps in config/rails.vim?) this extra path somehow? I'd like to use both of them.

I can navigate by hand like this:

```
:Rcontroller v1/api/messages_controller.rb
```

but :Rmodel from this controller does not work, it tries to jump to models/v1/api/model.rb

Answer (score 1):

This isn't tied into the rails.vim add-on, but you can add an additional command to do this for you. I believe this would be far easier than trying to modify the rails.vim source.

I actually [wrote a blog post](http://sudoit.org/2011/optimizing-gvim-a-newbies-use-of-commands/) about something similar. For your purposes, you'd want to put something like this in your vimrc:

```
command -nargs=? RcontrollerApi e \path\to\your\project\app\controllers\v1\api\<args>_controller.rb
```

You could then call it like this:

```
:RcontrollerApi messages
```

You wouldn't have the extra rails.vim sweetness that goes along with the native functionality, though (Like typing `:Rcontroller` in a view to automatically go to that file).

Here's an idea that may (or may not) work. I don't believe it will allow you to access the aforementioned functionality but it very well may point you in the right direction.

```
command -nargs=? RcontrollerApi Rcontroller v1/api/<args>_controller.rb
```